# Adding bass pedals to my keyboards

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I need some professional info and advice. I want to add a Viscount 9P6122722M1MD Midi pedalboard to my Tyros 4 and Korg PAX4. This is a mute pedalboard. I need this pedalboard to be able to play my bass when playing the keyboards as an organ, for pipe organ practice.

Will this be a good choice?

Please advise what mute means in this context. Does it mute the voice from the keyboard when the pedalboard is connected?

[image]

```
Viscount 9P6122722M1MD
MIDI Bass Pedal 27 N. - Straight Radiating
Dark Oak - Laminated
Bass Pedal
27 Keys pedal
Style: Radially straight
MIDI channels 1-16 programmable
Program change signal
Control change signal: 7 (volume) or 11 (expression) on pedals
2 Expression Pedals with independently programmable midi channels
Connectors: MIDI input 1 - MIDI input 2 - MIDI out - expression pedal 1 - expression pedal 2
2 LEDs status indicator
Colour: Dark oak
Dimensions:
Length: 1064 mm
Depth (with pedal): 931 mm
Depth (without pedal): 856 mm
Height (with pedal): 394 mm
Height (without pedal): 147 mm
```

https://www.thomann.de/gb/viscount_midi_bass_pedal_27.htm

Comment: I did similar with a pedalboard from an old electronic organ, using a MIDI module, a few years ago. Only one octave, not as nice as this radial, but at <£100 it works for me! Yes, for 'mute' read 'only makes sounds via a MIDI cable connected to something that does'!

Comment: Thanks for the Comment. I was wondering about making my own set with an old set of pedals from a Yamaha electone I have stored. My apology for sounding stupid. I understand mute was just not sure on the pedals. You know we live in SA. since 1994 we went 40 years backwards in time LOL.

Comment: It wasn't a difficult task - just a bit of a project, on the cheap! Fussy with all the wires from all the pedals. I'd love to find a 2 octave radial and do the same. Arduino was the interphase, I think. Works with any MIDI keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

This product is designed to connect to a device with a MIDI input. This could be a Viscount organ, your own keyboard, or many others.

It is called mute because it does not generate audio output, so you cannot connect it to speakers, whether directly or through an amplifier, and use it standalone. Instead, it generates MIDI note output. When you connect it to your keyboard, it will send events like "middle C was played", or "bottom E was released" to your keyboard, which will then generate your chosen sounds and send them to your chosen audio output.

It is not called mute because it will mute other output from your keyboard. It will not do that. However, you must configure it to use a different MIDI channel (in the given range 1-16) from those which your manuals are using. For example, if you were using a single keyboard, you could configure it to use MIDI channel 1, and the pedalboard to use MIDI channel 2. Instructions for how to do this will undoubtedly be in the manuals for your keyboard and pedalboard.

No doubt [Viscount themselves](https://viscountorgans.net/contact-us/) would be glad to answer more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the clear and well explained info. So I am on the right track. I understand the midi connections and the programing

Comment: You are welcome. I urge you to contact Viscount themselves to validate your plan. While I am confident about my advice, of course they can answer you with a higher level of confidence.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 27 note radiating (but not concave) church organ style pedalboard.  Slightly cut down from a full 32-note one. The bottom item on this page is almost the same model number!

https://www.viscountinstruments.com/media/wysiwyg/pdf/pdf/Elenco%20Pedaliere-%20ITA.pdf

Yes, it's designed to do what you require.   As commented above, 'mute' means it makes no sound of its own, it's purely a MIDI controller.

To emulate a 'two manuals plus pedal' organ, you'll have to connect a MIDI cable to one of your keyboards. It should be possible to program a patch that plays a suitable organ sound from the keyboard while responding to the pedals with another sound controlled by a specific MIDI channel.

Here's some discussion of how to do it on the Tyros

http://www.thelonearrangers.com/yamaha-tyros-1-2-3-4-5/2757-adding-bass-pedals-tyros-4-a.html